# Jython exceptions that subclass java.lang.Exception have an intermediary proxy subclass?

Tags: python, jython, python-2.x

I wanted to look at the behavior of subclassing a standard Java Exception class in Jython, and I noticed this:

```
C:\tmp>java -jar c:\app\java\lib\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar
Jython 2.5.3 (2.5:c56500f08d34+, Aug 13 2012, 14:54:35)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_91
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import java.lang.Exception
>>>
>>> class FooException(java.lang.RuntimeException):
...   def __init__(self, n):
...     super(FooException, self).__init__("I am a Foo and my number is %d" % n)
...
>>> def tryit(n):
...   try:
...     if n > 3:
...       raise FooException(n)
...   except FooException, e:
...     print "caught it:", e
...     print "class:              ", e.__class__
...     print "base class:         ", e.__class__.__bases__
...     print "base of base class: ", e.__class__.__bases__[0].__bases__
...     print isinstance(e, java.lang.Exception)
...
>>> tryit(4)
caught it: org.python.proxies.__main__$FooException$0: I am a Foo and my number is 4
class:               <class '__main__.FooException'>
base class:          (<type 'org.python.proxies.__main__$FooException$0'>,)
base of base class:  (<type 'java.lang.RuntimeException'>,)
True
>>> issubclass(FooException, java.lang.Exception)
True
```

**Why the intermediary class?**

Same behavior on Jython 2.7.0.

Here's the input code in case anyone wants to try it themselves:

```
import java.lang.Exception

class FooException(java.lang.RuntimeException):
  def __init__(self, n):
    super(FooException, self).__init__("I am a Foo and my number is %d" % n)

def tryit(n):
  try:
    if n > 3:
      raise FooException(n)
  except FooException, e:
    print "caught it:", e
    print "class:              ", e.__class__
    print "base class:         ", e.__class__.__bases__
    print "base of base class: ", e.__class__.__bases__[0].__bases__
    print isinstance(e, java.lang.Exception)

tryit(4)
issubclass(FooException, java.lang.Exception)
```

Comment: `isinstance` returned `False` because you called it on the `FooException` type, not an instance. You want `issubclass`.

Comment: just figured that out myself, thanks. Fixed!

Comment: Googling `jython proxy class` turns up [a bit of documentation](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PyProxy.html), but not a complete answer. Any answer to this question is going to have to dig into the details and limitations of how Jython implements Java/Python class interoperability.

Comment: Jython creates proxy classes any time a python class subclasses a java class so that it can map between the python and java semantics and handle the differences between python's multiple-inheritance versus java's single-inheritance.

Comment: @dsh: Why does that have to be a separate class from `FooException`, though? As someone unfamiliar with Jython's implementation details, it's not clear why that functionality couldn't be folded into `FooException` directly, rather than injecting a separate class between `FooException` and `java.lang.Exception`.